# Specify routes and verbs above controller actions

Tags: sails.js

Is it possible to specify routes and accepted verbs above controller actions, without having to have to specify it in config/routes.js ?

```
module.exports = {
    // GET /users
    getAllUsers: function (req, res) {
        User.find().exec(function (err, obj) {
            res.send(obj);
        });
    },
    // GET /users/:id
    getUserByID: function (req, res) {
        User.find({id:req.params.id}).exec(function (err, obj) {
            res.send(obj);
        });
    },
    // POST /users
    createUser: function (req, res) {
        User.create(req.body).exec(function (err, obj) {
            res.send(201, obj);
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not currently supported by Sails.  However, if you're just trying to create RESTful routes for a model, Sails gives you those for free via the [blueprints](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/blueprint-api) system.  So by default, if you have a `api/models/User.js` file and a `api/controllers/UserController.js` file, then the following routes are added automatically:

```
GET    /user     ==> UserController.find
GET    /user/:id ==> UserController.findOne
POST   /user     ==> UserController.create
PUT    /user/:id ==> UserController.update
DELETE /user/:id ==> UserController.destroy
```

There are default handlers for these actions, or you can override them in your controller file.

For models with [associations to other models](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations), some extra routes are also added.  See the [full blueprint API](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/blueprint-api) reference for details.

Note that you can also bind route handlers directly in the `config/routes.js` file, e.g. `"get /foo": function(req, res) {...}`, but that sorta defeats the purpose of using an MVC framework.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I [tweeted](https://twitter.com/gauiis/status/546101703075172352) asking them about this and I got a "yep!", even though the docs had nothing covered about this. Do you know if this will be added, as Express (which Sails is built on) has this feature.

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at, but it's not quite accurate to say that Express supports this. Express doesn't have controllers; you just bind routes directly to handlers with `app.get`, `app.post`, `app.all`, etc.  You can do the same thing in Sails by just bypassing controllers and placing your route handlers directly in the `config/routes.js` file (see the edit to my answer above).